# Event handler for COM object with win32com

Tags: python, events, handler, win32com

I have a problem with firing Events on `COM` object `"MCB.PCM"` in python. I use `win32com` package and application `fmstr (COM Object "MCB.PCM")` is running in parallel which I want to communicate with.

This code works on python console but there is no event fired and even application running in parallel is frozen as `Event` occurs

```
>>> class fmstrEvents(object):
    ...     def OnRecroderDone(self):
    ...         print "Hello OnRecroderDone"

>>> import win32com.client
>>> fm = win32com.client.Dispatch("MCB.PCM")
>>> fm_events = win32com.client.WithEvents(fm,fmstrEvents)
```

Do I miss something in code or incorrectly handling the events or `COM Object`?

Other question I have is that I am able to use `COM Object` methods as soon as those methods pass/return `VARIANT` e.g.

```
>>> fm.ReadVariable("dwt")
    (True, 0.009999999776482582, u'0.01', u'') 

    HRESULT ReadVariable(
            [in] VARIANT bsVar, 
            [out, optional] VARIANT* vValue, 
            [out, optional] VARIANT* tValue, 
            [out, optional] VARIANT* bsRetMsg, 
            [out, retval] VARIANT* pOk);
```

But I do know how access (read) `VARIANT` array which method returns e.g.

```
 >>> fm.GetCurrentRecorderData
<bound method IMcbPcm.GetCurrentRecorderData of <win32com.gen_py.MCB PCMaster Services.IMcbPcm instance at 0x110857432

 HRESULT GetCurrentRecorderData(
            [out, optional] VARIANT* arrData, 
            [out, optional] VARIANT* arrSerieNames, 
            [out, optional] VARIANT* timeBaseSec, 
            [out, optional] VARIANT* bsRetMsg, 
            [out, retval] VARIANT* pOk);
```

So `COM Object` method works but I need to get `VARRIANT` array data (`VARIANT* arrData`) to further process it.

Thank you very much.

Peter

P.S. I work with this `COM Object` in Matlab that I am able to register and handle events, work with `COM Object` methods etc... I would love to have it in python as well.

Comment: I figure out to get array from return VARIANAT array pointer as rec_data(0)[item]

Comment: There is a typo in the event method, it should be `OnRecorderDone`. However, you posted same question on another forum where you indicated that still doesn't fix the problem. The only other thing that comes to mind is that the COM class must support makepy, so try using `EnsureDispatch` instead of `Dispatch`.